# Accurately measure the execution time of async functions each time

Tags: javascript, performance, event-loop

```js
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

Array.from({ length: 10 }).map(async () => {
  const begin = performance.now()
  await timeout(1000) // demo io operation
  console.log(performance.now() - begin) // expect 1000ms ~ 1050ms
})
```

When the number of executions is small, the difference between the actual result and the expected result is not significant.

However, when the number of executions is large, the difference between the actual result and the expected result is significant.

```js
Array.from({ length: 10000 }).map(async () => {
  const begin = performance.now()
  await timeout(1000) // demo io operation
  console.log(performance.now() - begin) // actual longer and longer
})
```

I know that the reason is that the lot of microtasks in the event loop will affect the execution time of the next task. This is also normal.

But I want to know how to get the expected result.

Thanks for your help.

Ignoring the impact of task queues and accurately monitoring the time spent on a time-consuming operation.

Comment: Unless the API itself returns the time taken, this is impossible. You will always be limited by the task queue in observing the result.

Comment: The question is unclear. You say that you realize that the behavior is "normal", but you still want it to behave differently.

Comment: What is "the expected result"?

Comment: Your browser certainly has developer tools, which certainly contain a "Performance" tool that will help you analyze the runtime performances.